# How can I tell if one defrag utility is better than another?

Tags: windows-7, defragment

There's a lot of free defrag utilities (such as [Smart Defrag](http://www.iobit.com/iobitsmartdefrag.html), [Auslogics Disk Defrag](http://www.auslogics.com/en/software/disk-defrag/), [JKDefrag](http://kessels.biz/JkDefrag/), [Defraggler](http://www.piriform.com/defraggler), and there's alot more)

But are they actually any better than the built in Windows one?
And how can I tell?

Comment: What windows one? It was completely rewritten in Vista.

Comment: fwiw, piriform one is called defraggler

Comment: Better how? Faster? More power efficient? Lower residual fragmentation level? I use Defraggler because I like that I can choose which files to defrag, but "better" is subjective.

Comment: @RandolphWest By better I mean which does a better job defragging. I'm not concerned with speed or fancy featurse.

Comment: Which defrags best is a bit of a moot question, if they all finish defragmenting they will be no fragments left regardless. They only thing that will stop them deal with a fragmented file is unmovable files, which would happen to any program. So what quality would make one "Best?"

Comment: Well most of those programs advertise how they optimize your hard drive for optimal performance, and I'm sure they all don't optimize it the same. So really I guess the question should be which optimizes best...

Comment: I would stick to windows native defrag tool.

Comment: I'm leaning towards PerfectDisk because of personal experience (was better at optimizing the hard disk compared to other defraggers I've tried) and because of its defragmentation method: *SMARTPlacement is PerfectDisk's patented default method that defragments all files, consolidates free space, and optimizes the drive according to file usage. It provides the most complete defragmentation possible and slows down refragmentation of the drive.* It also has a free version last time I checked: http://www.neowin.net/news/raxco-goes-freeware-with-its-popular-perfectdisk

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's very relative, but one of the things I'd look at is *why* and *what* I'm defragmenting.

I've stopped defragmenting my Windows 7 systems manually because it's automatic. My Windows XP systems use the last available version of [JkDefrag](http://kessels.com/jkdefrag/) - it runs portably (which is useful since in some cases, I go into a service call, and magically fix a slow computer by defragging it), I can set it as a screensaver, and it's simple. On the other hand, the newer version, [MyDefrag](http://www.mydefrag.com/) is scriptable, and can be run on a schedule.

These are the things I'd look at in addition to the obvious stuff like speed and resource usage:

1. Can I pick a defragmenting pattern? This should minimally support a regular defragmentation, fast and slow zone defragmentation (which most good software supports)
2. Is boot-time defragmentation a feature I want? Some software supports it, and it's useful for page file defragmentation
3. Does it do scheduled defragmentation or can I set it as a screensaver?
4. Whether you actually need third party defragmentation software.

Answer (score 1):

Defragmentation is just an algorithm so this means people can write better algorithms, such as algorithms that optimise the hard drive while it defrags. So, algorithms with fancy features.

They are all going to have more features than the standard Win defrag utility, because it's not a highly developed or frequently updated product. I think a lot of the choice is going to come down to personal preference and bundled features.

For example I use Auslogics because it allows me to optimize my hard disks to different profiles while I am de-fragmenting them. It performs this optimization by moving files you wish to access faster to the centre of your hard disk - which means less time is needed to read the data because it's closer together.

[image]

Auslogics Defrag free only allows you to do this with system files, the paid version has many more algorithms for different purposes.

To answer the question "How can I tell" I would suggest checking out the overviews of each product to see what features they contain that you'd want to use. You could also check search engines for benchmarking information, but performance speed doesn't seem important factor for a defragger to me. I leave them on overnight anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> But are they actually any better than the built in Windows one?

Better? Well there's many discussions about this but I would like to stress on the fact that *fragmentation have an impact on system performances only when you have to read often files* such as Web Browser's cache for example but have no impact on performances for files such as Restore Points which, most of the time, are never to be read (unless you have to restore and for one time only...).

Therefore a better defragmenter than the Windows native's one must allow (at least) a *targeted* defragmentation and not only a entire disk volume defragmentation...

For such targeted defragmentation I have two suggestions for you:

1- Sysinternals *contig*: easy to use but limited in features

or (a better solution *imho*)

2- Ultradefrag:

You have to know that Ultradefrag do not use complex algorithms for defragmentations like JKDefrag ot other softwares but it's easy to use and give reasonable results... There's a *GUI* and command lines options with a (very) good documentation.

Ultradefrag may be run at *boot time* and run as *command line* for targeted defragmentation. For example you may keep the various command lines in a scheduled task and keep it disabled to run it only on demand if you want...

Examples:

```
udefrag "%APPDATA%\Mozilla*"

cmd.exe /C "set UD_SIZELIMIT=100M && udefrag --wait --all-fixed"
```

[ultradefrag at sourceforge](http://ultradefrag.sourceforge.net/en/index.html)

Hope this help. Let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Diskeeper? It's not free - but removes and PREVENTS fragmentation automatically using only idle system resources.

[image]

-Alex

Comment: As much as I'd like to have this program, I'm looking for freeware :)

Comment: How is this better than any other?

Answer (score -1):

I personally recommend [Defraggler](http://www.piriform.com/defraggler). It's simple, has all options one would look for but comes with a great default setup so you also can simply click defrag and wait. It can also completely replace the Windows 7 default defrag-algorithm and is updated on a six weeks cycle, so it will always be up to date.

[image]

Comment: How is this better than any other?